# How to show circular reference in dataframe columns

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, group-by, circular-reference

I am trying to understand the movement of product, the sample dataframe/table is included below.

| date | origin | destination | cost | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | A | B | 50.00 | 450 |
| 1/2/2022 | C | D | 75.00 | 540 |
| 1/3/2022 | B | A | 100.00 | 450 |
| 1/4/2022 | E | F | 50.00 | 540 |
| 1/5/2022 | C | B | 25.00 | 300 |

I want to be able to show the cost and volume associated with the "inefficient routes", i.e. A to B to A. I'm actually using a much larger dataset so it is harder to see the inefficiencies.

Is there a way to compute this in python or excel?

I tried using groupby in pandas, `df.groupby(['origin', 'destination']).size()`  and `df.groupby(['origin','destination']).sum()` but those don't make it easier to see where the product goes back to it's origin site (A to B back to A).

Sample output would be a or dataframe of inefficient lanes.
|route|cost|
|-----|----|
|A->B->A|150.00|
|...|...|

Comment: Can you add a sample of the expected output to the question?

Comment: @Clegane sample output added to the original question